# Add CSS to HTML generated email on send_dbmail on SQL Server

Tags: html, css, sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I'm trying to add CSS on report emails generated thru stored procedures in SQL Server. The function is working, except that when I receive it on my email, the CSS on the status shows like this:

[image]

This what I did to code the CSS:

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @html NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @xml = CAST((
SELECT 
TransactionTable.RequestName as 'td',
 CASE WHEN  TransactionTable.Approved = 0  THEN '<p style="font-weight:bold;color: rgb(209, 168, 35);">PENDING</p>'
 WHEN  TransactionTable.Approved = NULL THEN '<p style="font-weight:bold;color: rgb(209, 168, 35);">PENDING</p>'
 WHEN TransactionTable.Approved = 1  THEN '<p style="font-weight:bold;color: rgb(35, 209, 35);">APPROVED</p>' 
 WHEN TransactionTable.Approved = 2  THEN '<p style="font-weight:bold;color: rgb(228, 26, 26);">REJECTED</p>' 
 ELSE
 '<p style="color: rgb(209, 168, 35);">PENDING</p>'
 END  as 'td',
TransactionTable.Comments as 'td',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TransactionTable.ApprovedDate, 100) as 'td',
from 
TransactionTable  
ORDER BY ApproverOrder FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS XSINIL) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));

SET @html = '<html>
                 <head>
                     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+2&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
                     <style>
                       body {font-family:''Baloo 2'';}
                     </style>
                     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
                 </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Request Name</td>
                        <td>Status</td>
                        <td>Comment</td>
                        <td>Update On</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    '+ @xml +'
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
            </html>';

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @importance='Normal',
        @FROM_address='noreply@mail.com',
        @body =  @html,
        @body_format ='HTML',
        @recipients = 'myemail@mail.com',
        @subject = 'ApprovalReport' ;
```

Is there something I need to do for the CSS to work properly before I run the `sp_send_dbmail`?

Comment: `, CAST(CASE WHEN TransactionTable.Approved = 0 THEN....</p>' END AS XML) as 'td',...`

Comment: Print out `@html` and inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `FOR XML PATH` isn't producing what you expect. If you reduce it to a minimal example this is what you're code is doing:

```sql
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @xml = CAST((
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN  Approved = 0  THEN '<p style="font-weight:bold;color: rgb(209, 168, 35);">PENDING</p>'
 WHEN  Approved = NULL THEN '<p style="font-weight:bold;color: rgb(209, 168, 35);">PENDING</p>'
 WHEN Approved = 1  THEN '<p style="font-weight:bold;color: rgb(35, 209, 35);">APPROVED</p>' 
 WHEN Approved = 2  THEN '<p style="font-weight:bold;color: rgb(228, 26, 26);">REJECTED</p>' 
 ELSE
 '<p style="color: rgb(209, 168, 35);">PENDING</p>'
 END  as 'td'
from (values (1,1)) T(ApproverOrder, Approved)
ORDER BY ApproverOrder FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS XSINIL) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
select @xml;
```

Which produces:

```
<tr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><td>&lt;p style="font-weight:bold;color: rgb(35, 209, 35);"&gt;APPROVED&lt;/p&gt;</td></tr>
```

Notice how the `<` and `>` characters around your `p` tags have been encoded into `&lt;` and `&gt;` sequences. Try rearranging your code such that it's more like the following:

```sql
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @xml = CAST((
SELECT 
 CASE
   WHEN  Approved = 0  THEN 'font-weight:bold;color: rgb(209, 168, 35);'
   WHEN  Approved = NULL THEN 'font-weight:bold;color: rgb(209, 168, 35);'
   WHEN Approved = 1  THEN 'font-weight:bold;color: rgb(35, 209, 35);'
   WHEN Approved = 2  THEN 'font-weight:bold;color: rgb(228, 26, 26);'
   ELSE 'color: rgb(209, 168, 35);'
 END  as 'td/p/@style',
 CASE
   WHEN  Approved = 0  THEN 'PENDING'
   WHEN  Approved = NULL THEN 'PENDING'
   WHEN Approved = 1  THEN 'APPROVED'
   WHEN Approved = 2  THEN 'REJECTED'
   ELSE 'PENDING'
 END as 'td/p'
from (values (1,1)) T(ApproverOrder, Approved)
ORDER BY ApproverOrder FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS XSINIL) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
select @xml;
```

Which produces the output:

```
<tr xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><td><p style="font-weight:bold;color: rgb(35, 209, 35);">APPROVED</p></td></tr>
```